# I am unable to enter data into sql table using vb.net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

My table structure is :

```
       pid nvarchar(15) //foreign key
       mgfdate datetime
       duration numeric(18,0)
       warrantytype varchar(20)
       purchasedate datetime
       expirydate datetime
```

My Sql query is :

```
    Dim s1 as String = "insert into productwarranty values(@pid,@mgfdate,@warrantytype,@duration,@purchasedate,@expirydate)"

    Public Function prodwarrantyinsert(ByVal query As String, ByVal product As productform)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim d As Integer = CInt(product.ptb10.Text)
    Try
        connect()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conn)
        Dim ed As String = CStr(product.ptb11.Text)
        Dim md As String = product.pdt7.Value.ToString
        Dim pd As String = product.pdt9.Value.ToString
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", PID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mgfdate", md)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", d)
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warrantytype", product.ptb8.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@purchasedate", pd)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expirydate", ed)

        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        disconnect()
    End Try

    Return i
End Function
```

I constantly keep getting an error as "Error converting datatype nvarchar to numeric"

Any help would be appreciated guys.

Comment: Stupid question:  are you trying to stick text into a numeric field?

Comment: Try listing the Column Names:  insert into productwarranty(pid, mgfdate, warrantytype, duration , purchasedate ,expirydate).  It looks like mgfdate and warrantytype are out of order.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Buddy i understand plain english so i am aware that there is some datatype conflict between the table datatype and the passed value  but couldn't identify it.

Comment: @NicholasV. Pal it fails at i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't sepcify the column order in your insert, you *must* use the natural order in the `VALUES` section.  You seem to have `@warrantytype` and `@duration` swapped.  I would be safe and specify the columns:

```
Dim s1 as String = "insert into productwarranty " & _
                   "(pid, mgfdate, warrantytype, duration, purchasedate, expirydate) " & _                          
                   "values(@pid, @mgfdate, @warrantytype, @duration, @purchasedate, @expirydate)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to insert text

```
Dim ed As String = CStr(product.ptb11.Text)
```

into field of `datetime` type

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@expirydate", ed)
```

which maybe can't be converted.